# How do I apply this operation to a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have these two lists, `mylist = {{a,b},{c,d}}`, and `mysecondlist = {1,2}`

I want to generate this output: `output = {{{a,b,1},{a,b,2}},{{c,d,1},{c,d,2}}}`

In other words, `output[[1,1,1]] = {mylist[[1,1]],mysecondlist[[1]]}`, `output[[1,1,2]] = {mylist[[1,1]],mysecondlist[[2]]}`, and so on. The original 2D list becomes a 3D one.

I'm not actually sure what the name of the operation is, let alone which command to use in Mathematica. Is there a command that generates this, or do I have to do it with a Do loop that runs over all the possible indices and defines them one by one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Outer[Append, mylist, mysecondlist, 1]
```

> ```
> {{{a, b, 1}, {a, b, 2}}, {{c, d, 1}, {c, d, 2}}}
> ```

Also

```
Outer[Join, mylist, List /@ mysecondlist, 1]

Flatten /@ Tuples[{{#},  mysecondlist}] & /@ mylist

Flatten /@ Thread[{#, mysecondlist}, List, {2}] & /@ mylist 

Distribute[{mylist, mysecondlist}, List, List, Partition[{##}, 2] &, Append]
```

all give

> ```
>  {{{a, b, 1}, {a, b, 2}}, {{c, d, 1}, {c, d, 2}}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

My train of thought to tackle that problem would be the following:

Each of the elements of your desired solution has the elements of the second list appended.

I would first try to construct each element separately. The first element would be.

```
Append[{a, b}, #] & /@ mysecondlist
```

which gives

```
{{a, b, 1}, {a, b, 2}}
```

Afterwards I would replace `{a,b}` by a variable and use `Map` to obtain a list of all elements.

```
Function[{x}, Append[x, #] & /@ mysecondlist] /@ mylist
```

which gives

```
{{{a, b, 1}, {a, b, 2}}, {{c, d, 1}, {c, d, 2}}}
```

So in short: Try to divide the problem in smaller, easier solvable chunks.